# MongoDB bulkWrite() and stale reads

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Immediately after inserting documents using `db.collection.bulkWrite()` a query using the aggregate framework can often be stale (i.e. not all the 'inserted' documents are returned). Performing this exact same read immediately again could then return all the documents. Sometimes all the documents are returned first time and sometimes it can take 3 reads - there isn't any consistency to this.

I am doing this on my local MongoDB 3.2 instance (no sharding whatsoever - only a primary) with WriteConcern set to W1 (i.e. the write must be acknowledged on my only instance).

The profile on the insert:

[image: Profile]

The profile on the query:

[image: Profile]

What could possibly be happening?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I experience the same. I do bulkWrite with writeConcern of "majority", wait 10 seconds, do an aggregation, and it returns stale version of documents that bulkWrite have modified. Does not happen often, say a few times over 10'000 documents, but still happens consistently.